# css apenas para celular

Tags: css

Bom estou acostumado a verificar o css dessa forma:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {}
```

O problema e que tem celulares com resolução muito alta, tem alguma outra forma de eu verificar sem o uso do Px?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://coderwall.com/p/ygcyha/how-to-get-real-mobile-css-resolutions-for-responsive-design

Comment: Use Javascript e um [*pattern* para detectar](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) navegadores mobile. =)

Comment: Este artigo é sensacional http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: [Este artigo explica](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) muito bem sobre como detectar usando MediaQuery dispositivos moveis.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar o @media (pointer: coarse), com ele você consegue detectar se o usuário está usando um mouse ou navega através de uma tela touch, o interessante é que mesmo em notebooks com tela touch ele acusa o mouse como principal e entra no query

caso fique curioso segue exemplo prático que encontrei na net
http://codepen.io/andresgalante/pen/bBEJKg